# looking for a way to calculate Mac using the ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3(Retail MAC)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, hmac, 3des

Looking through Java Cryptography Architecture and code examples, I have learned how to calculate the Mac using Mac class:

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
mac.init(<secretKeyHere>);
byte[] macHash = mac.doFinal(<encryptedTextHere>);
```

But I am actually looking for a way to calculate Mac using the ISO 9797-1 Algorithm 3(Retail MAC).

Can someone suggest me a code example in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [not available in any](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html) of the Oracle providers, however if you add the Bouncycastle provider then that mac algorithm will be available, e.g.

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("ISO9797ALG3MAC");
```

Note: that Mac algorithm has been obsolete for decades.

Comment: Thank you very much! I gave it a quick try and it looks like it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to look at [`javacard.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_DES_MAC4_ISO9797_1_M2_ALG3)`](https://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/Signature.html#ALG_DES_MAC4_ISO9797_1_M2_ALG3) and then use the `init()`, `update()`, and `sign()` methods to generate that specific signature.